# Как расширить\врапнуть аттрибутную angular.js директиву ? (ui bootstrap tooltip)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

Мы всегда можем написать:

```
<span ng-bind="employee.name" uib-tooltip="employee.name+employee.age+employee.xyz"></span>
```

Но всегда лучше энкапсулировать это в link функции директивы, где обработать employee в строку в $scope `$scope.string` и добавить `uib-tooltip="{{string}}"` аттрибут к исходному элементу.

```
 <span ng-bind="employee.name" employee-tooltip="employee"></span>
```

Вопрос в том "как" ?

Не подходящие ответы:

1. Через template `template:<span uib-tooltip="{{string}}></span>`.                        Аттрибутная директива должна оставаться аттрибутом.
2. Через `replace:true`. Мы потеряем все аттрибуты исходного элемента и  div/li/img/input станут span.

Comment: _Мы потеряем все аттрибуты исходного элемента_ - все атрибуты как раз останутся на месте, но сам элемент заменится на тот который указан в шаблоне

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В своей директиве можно воспользоваться [сервисом *$compile*](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)

А также выставить свойства *priority* в высокое значение, чтобы директива обрабатывалась первой, и свойство *terminal* - в *true*, чтобы после обработки данной директивы другие не обрабатывались.

В функции `link` нужно удалить атрибут соответствующий директиве, добавить необходимые атрибуты со значениями, и применить `$compile`.

<sub>на основе ответа [Add directives from directive in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19224028/add-directives-from-directive-in-angularjs)</sub>

Пример:

```js
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('TooltipDemoCtrl', function($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.employee = {
    name: "Employee",
    age: "20",
    xyz: "XYZ"
  }
}).directive('my1', function($compile) {
  return {
    priority: 1001,
    terminal: true,
    link: function link(scope, el, attrs) {
      var linkFn = $compile(
        el.removeAttr('my1')
        .attr('tooltip-placement', 'right')
        .attr('uib-tooltip', '{{employee.name + employee.age + employee.xyz}}')
      );
      linkFn(scope);
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.1.4.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo" ng-controller="TooltipDemoCtrl">
  <span my1 ng-bind="employee.name">
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Отлично, именно то, что требовалось, спасибо!